# Meaning of "Eligible Situation"

Tags: adjectives

In this excerpt from Northanger Abbey, Mrs. Allen and her protegee Catherine are at a ball where they are not acquainted with anyone:

> They saw nothing of Mr. Allen; and after looking about them in vain
>   for a more eligible situation, were obliged to sit down at the end of
>   a table, at which a large party were already placed, without having
>   anything to do there, or anybody to speak to, except each other.

What does the author mean by *eligible* situation? The two dictionary definitions of eligible do not seem to match how it is used.

Comment: A situation in which they can engage without breaking social customs. Mr Allen was not present to introduce them.

Comment: That is very different from today, when some kind soul might see them floundering and ask "hey guys, can I get you a drink?"

Comment: Hello, 542. You do need to give those definitions, with attributions and links. You say there are two; how many dictionaries have you checked in? One general sense is 'meeting the desired conditions / suitable'.

Answer (score 1):

**Eligible** (adj) [definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/definition/eligible)

worthy to be chosen or selected; suitable; desirable;

> an **eligible situation** for a house

As in:  [eligible situation in google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=zoEwAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22eligible%20situation%22&pg=PA222#v=onepage&q=%22eligible%20situation%22&f=false)

> Did you examine the ground, or are you sufficiently acquainted with
>   it, to state your opinion, if it is the most **eligible situation** for a
>   depot for a Railroad, for the town of Brighton ?

And  [sniggle.com](https://sniggle.net/Hasheesh/TheHasheeshEater/Notes/n55261.html)

> eligible situation — that is, “good location”